# How to remove repetitive entries in files

Tags: python, perl, file

I have a file (input.txt )with lines such as :

```
1_306500682 2_315577060 3_315161284 22_315577259 22_315576763 

2_315578866 2_315579020 3_315163106 1_306500983 

2_315579517 3_315162181 1_306502338 2_315578919 

1_306500655 2_315579567 3_315161256 3_315161708
```

From this, I only want to keep first entries in each line having repetitive values before _. For the above example, the output.txt should contain:

```
1_306500682 2_315577060 3_315161284 22_315577259 

2_315578866 3_315163106 1_306500983 

2_315579517 3_315162181 1_306502338 

1_306500655 2_315579567 3_315161256
```

plz help..

Comment: StackOverflow is a site where you post questions about a problem you are having, not a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: Yes, that is what you want to do, and that is how it should look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -lane 'my %s;print join " ", grep /^(\d+)_/ && !$s{$1}++, @F' file
```

output

```
1_306500682 2_315577060 3_315161284 22_315577259

2_315578866 3_315163106 1_306500983

2_315579517 3_315162181 1_306502338

1_306500655 2_315579567 3_315161256
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        seen = set()
        nums = line.split()
        for num in nums:
            header = num.split("_")[0]
            if header not in seen:
                outfile.write(num)
                outfile.write(" ")
            seen.add(header)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate `set` to keep track of the word prefixes encountered so far and gather the non-repetitive ones from each line into a `list`. After processing each line that way, a replacement line of text can easily be constructed containing only the non-repetitive entries that were found. Note: This is just a slightly more efficient version of inspectorG4dget's current answer.

```
with open('input.txt', 'rt') as infile, \
     open('non_repetitive_input.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        values, prefixes = [], set()
        for word, prefix in ((entry, entry.partition('_')[0])
                                for entry in line.split()):
            if prefix not in prefixes:
                values.append(word)
                prefixes.add(prefix)
        outfile.write(' '.join(values) + '\n')
```

Output file's contents:

```
1_306500682 2_315577060 3_315161284 22_315577259
2_315578866 3_315163106 1_306500983
2_315579517 3_315162181 1_306502338
1_306500655 2_315579567 3_315161256
```